# How to build a multindexed transition matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I start with the following tabular data  : (let's say tests results by version)

```
    Item  Result   Version
0   TO     OK      V1
1   T1    NOK      V1
2   T2     OK      V1
3   T3    NOK      V1
4   TO     OK      V2
5   T1     OK      V2
6   T2    NOK      V2
7   T3    NOK      V2
```

```
df=p.DataFrame({'Item': ['TO','T1','T2','T3','TO','T1','T2','T3'],
                'Version': ['V1','V1','V1','V1','V2','V2','V2','V2'],
                'Result' : ['OK','NOK','OK','NOK','OK','OK','NOK','NOK']})
```

and I try to build the following report:

```
            V2
            OK      NOK
V1  OK      T0      T2
    NOK     T1      T3
```

(`T0` above should be a python **set** resulting from aggregation with `set` function), and I would like to have multiindexes on both rows and cols.

I can't figure how to put the same "Result" col in **both** rows and columns multiindexes.  Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, basically we can treat this as long to wide question by using `pivot`

```
df['New']=list(zip(df.Version,df.Result))
s=df.groupby('Item').New.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).reset_index().pivot(0,1,'Item')
s
Out[502]:
1         (V2, NOK) (V2, OK)
0
(V1, NOK)        T3       T1
(V1, OK)         T2       TO


s.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.index)
s.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.columns)
s
Out[507]: 
        V2    
       NOK  OK
V1 NOK  T3  T1
   OK   T2  TO
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution using `pd.pivot_table`:

```
g = df.groupby('Item')['Result'].apply(list).reset_index()

g[['V1', 'V2']] = g['Result'].apply(pd.Series)

res = g.pivot_table(index='V1', columns='V2', values='Item', aggfunc='first')

print(res)

V2  NOK  OK
V1         
NOK  T3  T1
OK   T2  TO
```

Comment: @Wen, Probably, this is  just another idea if you only have one value for the first level.

Comment: Fair enough :-)